# How do you separate the column in R?

Tags: r

In my dataset (which is on gun violence), each column has || in between the data points.

e.g Age

```
0::Male||1::Female||2::Male||
```

How do you separate the data points?

Thanks!

Comment: Usually, this is done with something called a "split". I'm unfamiliar with R, but I think there should be such a feature to split a string by "||". A search on that might be helpful.

Comment: I think you should show more of the appearance of the raw text file.

Answer (score 0):

`read.table`/`read.delim` allows you define a *single* character by which values in each line are separated (see argument `sep` in `?read.table`).

Since you have `||`, all we need to do is remove the resulting `NA` columns when reading the data.

Here is an example:

```
# Sample data
df <- read.table(text =
    "0::Male||1::Female||2::Male||
    0::Male||1::Female||2::Male||
    0::Male||1::Female||2::Male||
    0::Male||1::Female||2::Male||", sep = "|")

# Remove NA columns
df[, !sapply(df, function(x) all(is.na(x)))]
#           V1        V3      V5
#1     0::Male 1::Female 2::Male
#2     0::Male 1::Female 2::Male
#3     0::Male 1::Female 2::Male
#4     0::Male 1::Female 2::Male
```